# Creating a ease scrolling effect onscroll

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I found this codepen of a smooth scrolling effect using a combination of both js and css. I've been trying to find a way to duplicate this using only pure css and tailwind. **Is it possible to do it only using pure css or tailwind?**

examples:
https://codepen.io/origine/pen/gvpWRY
or
https://www.korupartners.com

```
const body = document.body,
      jsScroll = document.getElementsByClassName('js-scroll')[0],
      height = jsScroll.getBoundingClientRect().height - 1,
      speed = 0.05

var offset = 0

body.style.height = Math.floor(height) + "px"

function smoothScroll() {
    offset += (window.pageYOffset - offset) * speed
    
    var scroll = "translateY(-" + offset + "px) translateZ(0)"
    jsScroll.style.transform = scroll
    
    raf = requestAnimationFrame(smoothScroll)
}
smoothScroll()
```

I tried searching for smooth scrolling effects but they all refer to the on-click section scroll type, not the literal on scroll ease effect.